# Position two anchors next to each other with inline-block without floating

Tags: html, css

I've got two buttons I want to float next to each other.

This all works perfectly fine until I add a width to one of the buttons. The button now jumps down and is not on the same line anymore as the other button.

The buttons are centered so can't be floated.

Any ideas on how to get these buttons next to each other that do not involve floating?

```css
.home_topbar .more_information, .home_topbar .order_now {
        margin: 80px 0 0;
    }
    .home_topbar .more_information {
        margin-right: 15px;
        width: auto;
    }
    .home_topbar .order_now {
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 400px;
    }
    
        .button {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 60px;
        padding: 0 15px 0 30px;
        color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #000;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        line-height: 60px;
    }
```

```html
    <a href="" class="more_information button">
        abc
    </a>
    
    <a href="" class="order_now button">
        def
    </a>
```

Comment: Please add a fiddle as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using the `white-space` property.

If this is your **HTML** modify your **CSS** as follows:

```css
.button {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 60px;
        padding: 0 15px 0 30px;
        color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background: #000;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #FFF;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        line-height: 60px;
    }
    .home_topbar {
        border: 1px dashed blue;
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: center; /* to center buttons */
        min-width: 550px; /* One way of dealing with overflow... */
    }
    .home_topbar .more_information, .home_topbar .order_now {
        margin: 80px 0 0;
    }
    .home_topbar .more_information {
        margin-right: 15px;
        width: auto;
    }
    .home_topbar .order_now {
        margin-left: 15px;
        width: 400px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="home_topbar">
    <a href="" class="more_information button">abc</a>
    <a href="" class="order_now button">def</a>
    </div>
```

On the parent container `.home_topbar`, add `white-space: nowrap` and this will prevent the two inline elements from wrapping onto a second line as the window width decreases.

However, as you decrease the window width, you will eventually trigger an overflow condition that will generate a horizontal scroll bar so you need to decide how to handle that (min-width value?).

Note that if you specify a `min-width` value, then you may not need the `nowrap` value.

If you want a more responsive design, I would use CSS table cells.

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/g6LWc/

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/#white-space-property